# Force Stop Scrolling

Tags: java, android, scroll

How To "Force Stop" a Scrollable View (like a ListView) From Scrolling?

I want to stop a scrollable view from scrolling.
Is there a method to do this? I want it to stop after I "TOUCH"
the EditText. The scrollable view must not be disabled from
scrolling, but if this happens I want to enable it again after the
dispatching process of the the view after the touch.

In summary, the scrollable view must force stop (not disabling from scrolling)
even if it is scrolling by touching an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

May just call

```
listView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0);
```

to stop its scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, does it force stop the listview even if it is scrolling by using this method?